# Django / Python catch exception not working?

Tags: python, django, exception

Should this code not be working?

```
    if request.GET.has_key("category"):
        try:
            post_list = post_list.filter(category=request.GET.get("category"))
        except ValueError:
            print "Category is not an integer"
```

Category is an IntegerField. I'm trying to handle the case when a user enters the URL `http://myurl.com?category=` where category has no value.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It has an indentation error ;)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you're talking about the `if` indentation and the code inside it, it's correct on my IDE. SO doesn't like to paste indentations correctly...

Comment: "SO doesn't like to paste indentations correctly".  That's always been false in my experience.  Odds are good you still have something else wrong like mixed tabs and spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
category = request.GET.get("category")
if category:
    try:
        post_list = post_list.filter(category=int(category))
    except ValueError:
        print "That's not an integer"
```

Comment: +1, i think it's better to just do : `category = request.GET.get("category")` and by default category will be None if it's not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

No need for the `if` statement, `request.GET.get` will return None if it's not set.

```
try:
    post_list = post_list.filter(category=int(request.GET.get("category")))
except ValueError:
    print "Category is not an integer"
except TypeError:
    print "no Category passed.."
```

Comment: I take that back. I got a `int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'` without the if

Comment: ah, right.. that's a `TypeError`, not `ValueError`; edited the answer